# Nodejs ignoring cwd while spawning a child process

Tags: node.js

I am trying to spawn a child process with a default directory. The process is being executed and it is able to read the args. But the process starts up in the current directory, even though I am providing cwd as options. Am I doing this incorrectly?

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var child = spawn("sh",
   ["path_to_file_name", "args"],
   [{cwd:"/some/path/temp"}]
);
```

My end goal is to execute a bash script, in a specific folder so that it doesn't mess up my application directory.

Node version : 4.0.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`options` is an object, not array.

```
var child = spawn("sh",
   ["path_to_file_name", "args"],
   {cwd:"/some/path/temp"}
);
```

Comment: When I try running it as an object, the bash script doesn't run at all.

Comment: You know what, I made a small mistake, and I realised that the path was having an issue... thx for the pointer. The issue is fixed.